# Avoid auto running job when altering repeating intervals in Oracle 11g using Toad 10.6.1.3

Tags: oracle11g, jobs, scheduler, toad, alter

OK here is the deal,

I have an Oracle 11g job that runs everyday, at a given Hour.

My iterval is:   FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=**10**;BYMINUTE=5;

By using TOAD 10.6.1.3, I get in to scheduled jobs, find my job then right click and select Alter scheduler job.

I change the interval to:          FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=**11**;BYMINUTE=5;

The job is altered, but it also runs (executes it's code) at the same time is altered and that is incorrect !

Is there a way to avoid running the job after altering it, or is this a bug from toad?

SQL Developer seems to do it correctly with out running the job, so im not in a hurry. I just want to know why Toad is doing that, and how to prevent it.

Thanks

Comment: Is worth to mention that if I run this manually, it works correctly:

BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'SCHEMA.MYJOB'
     ,attribute => 'REPEAT_INTERVAL'
     ,value     => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=11;BYMINUTE=5');
END;

Answer (score 1):

Are you current on your Support agreement?  This sounds like a bug, but I'd suggest you open a case with Quest Software's Technical Support group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no we are not